# Allow only update in Django rest api framework

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I am working on a very simple application that has only 1 model with a couple of fields. I want these models to be created or deleted only through the /admin pages (through the standard Django admin framework) and allow the rest api framework to only alter these objects.

Is there any simple way to make it happen?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you want to disable the update in the admin and allow only the update via rest framework?

Comment: @fasouto I want to disable create and delete in the rest framework and enable update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need set up `http_method_names` same as below:

```
class WebViewSet(mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                 mixins.ListModelMixin,
                 mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
                 viewsets.GenericViewSet):

    model = WebTransaction
    http_method_names = ('get', 'put')
```

Answer (score 2):

Just create a viewset that uses update/retrieve model mixen.

```
from rest_framwork import viewsets, mixins
class FooViewSet(mixens.RetrieveModelMixin,
                 mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
                 viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    model = Foo
    queryset = Foo.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FooSerializer
```

This will only give you an APIEnd points to retrieve or update an instance of your model.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just update the objects use [UpdateApiView](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#updateapiview). With this view you will create just the update(PUT Method) for you model.Any doubts follow the documentation in [Documentation DRF](http://www.cdrf.co/3.1/rest_framework.generics/UpdateAPIView.html).

Comment: Welcome to SO! Just include link is not a good answer. Link could be inaccessible over time. Please read this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to follow the guidelines there.